# Importing a package into a java file from a different subdirectory

Tags: java, directory, package

i have a directory structure, the main directory being TOP, with two sub directories, Left and Right. If I have a class in Left that i want to import into Right, how would i do that? I keep getting: "Package Top.Right does not exist" error when i try to import Top.Right in the java class file in the Left sub directory. In the java class in Right, i make sure to type "package Top.Right"

Is there something else i am missing? Is there something with classpath that i need to add?

Edit1: Sorry, here is some source code

This is the Left sub directory class

```
package Left;
import Top.Right.*;
public class leftClass{

private int num;

public leftClass(int hello){
    rightClass five = new rightClass(5);
    num = five.getNum();

}
public int getNum(){
    return this.num;
}
public void setNum(int numset){
    this.num = numset;
}

}
```

This is the Right sub directory class

```
package Top.Right;

public class rightClass{

private int num;

public rightCase(int hello){
    num = hello;

}
public int getNum(){
    return this.num;
}
public void setNum(int numset){
    this.num = numset;
}   
}
```

leftClass is called by topClass, but that works fine.

Thanks for the help guys, if i'm missing any information please let me know!

Comment: You need to provide actual source code; don't paraphrase source or messages when asking questions on SO if you can help it. Add the source for the two classes to the above question.

Comment: shows us actual code.